# Find button control inside DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How do I find button control inside DataGridView, I would do something like this in asp.net for GridView

```
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridviewname.Rows)
    {
         Button btnColor= (Button)row.FindControl("btnColor");
    }
```

But I'm unable to-do the same in Windows forms application.Basically I'm trying to set property of button such as color,text etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you do not need to change individual buttons you can customize the entire button column through its [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) :

   You could get it during runtime like:

   ```
   buttonColumn = (DataGridViewButtonColumn)dataGridView.Columns
       .Where(column => column is DataGridViewButtonColumn)
       .First();
   ```
2. For individual cells you could try to change cell's [Style property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.style(v=vs.110).aspx)

   ```
   Boolean colorFlag = false;
   foreach (GridViewRow row in gridviewname.Rows)
   {         
       row[buttonColumn].Style.BackColor = (colorFlag) : Colors.Green? Colors.Red;
       colorFlag = !colorFlag;
   }
   ```

   But I'm not sure however that it will work - [Change Color of Button in DataGridView Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586829/change-color-of-button-in-datagridview-cell).

Answer (score 1):

In `datagridview` you can get  button through column.

```
this.mydatagridview.Columns("MybuttonColumn").DefaultCellStyle
```

Or if you have predefined columns then:

```
this.MyButtonColumn.DefaultCellStyle
```

Or if you use Visual Studio designer, then you can set column style values through designer.

Comment: Could you please give a small demo using this code?