# Deriving DataGridViewButtonColumn class and changing Button object

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I tried to create a child class of `DataGridViewButtonColumn` but I am stuck. The only property I can easily change now is `FlatStyle` that is part of Button class. Say I would like to change `ForeColor` (there are other things as well, `ForeColor` is just an example so please don't stick to that, i.e. don't use workaround like `DefaultCellStyle`). I thus would have to somehow retrieve Button object from `DataGridViewButtonColumn`. Inside `DataGridViewButtonColumn` there is `DataGridViewButtonCell`. This class (I believe) holds the Button and it has property named Value (derived from `DataGridViewCell`) but it is null in the `DataGridViewButtonCell`'s constructor thus I can't access it from there. How otherwise can I have any influence on the Button object inside the cell?

Here's example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class MyDataGridViewButtonColumn : DataGridViewButtonColumn
{
    public MyDataGridViewButtonColumn () : base()
    {
        ((Button)((DataGridViewButtonCell)this.CellTemplate).Value).ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

I'm new to manipulating with existing .NET controls but MSDN does not "support" it, meaning they do not really document examples of how to do so. My attempts I base on looking into .NET framework's code and learn from there.

I checked how they implemented FlatStyle, which I tought would call the Button object and set value to whatever I specify. However, the implementation was uknown to me.

```
public FlatStyle FlatStyle
{
    set
    {
        if (!ClientUtils.IsEnumValid(value, (int)value, 0, 3))
        {
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("value", (int)value, typeof(FlatStyle));
        }
        if (value != this.FlatStyle)
        {
            base.Properties.SetInteger(DataGridViewButtonCell.PropButtonCellFlatStyle, (int)value);
            base.OnCommonChange();
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like it changes some `Properties` class where each property (like `FlatStyle`) has it's own integer value? Does it work the same way for all properties? I doubt it's documented?

Edit: Do I see correctly that the Button is literally drawn inside the cell and not really created as an object?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution:

[Change Color of Button in DataGridView Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586829/change-color-of-button-in-datagridview-cell)

But read past the selected answer and I think you should focus on the answer provided by Mike Yasieniuk who's answer is actually up-voted more.

Hopefully that will help.

Comment: Unfortunatelly not because it's ForeColor of the cell. My important note was that it shouldn't be just limited to the forecolor. I would also like to change i.e. borders and paddings of the button itself. Such properties are not available in the `DefaultCellStyle`