# Change color of Button in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I have searched high and low for an answer to this question.The answer on this post: [Change Color of Button in DataGridView Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586829/change-color-of-button-in-datagridview-cell) does not answer my question as it regards font.

I have tried the following:

```
DataGridViewRow r = dataGridView.Rows[0];
r.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

I have also tried:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn btnCOl = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
btnCOl.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
DataGridViewRow r = dataGridView.Rows[0];
r.Cells[1].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle { BackColor = Color.LightBlue };
```

Still to no avail.

I also commented out this line:

```
// Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

If there is anyone who knows how to **change the background color of a single button in a DataGridViewButtonColumn**, please help.

**EDIT:**
I want to set different colors for the cells in the column e.g. some will be red while others will be green. I don't want to set the color for the whole column.

Comment: you can simply use btnCOl.Style.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This

```
DataGridViewButtonCell bc = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
bc.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
bc.Style.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
```

You can than assign this cell to the row you need

Here is a small example with a **DataGridView dgvSample** Already inserted in form

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    DataGridViewRow fr = new DataGridViewRow();
    fr.CreateCells(dgvSample);

    DataGridViewButtonCell bc = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
    bc.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;

    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        bc.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }   
    else
    {
        bc.Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }

    fr.Cells[0] = bc;
    dgvSample.Rows.Add(fr);
}
```

Comment: .NET surely knows how to bring on the pain. Why did they even add a barely functional DataGridViewButtonColumn class? Now I have to rewrite everything.

Comment: It is bc.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor  instead of bc.Style.BackColor

Answer (score 10):

**Change BackColor of the whole Column**

As an option you can set [`FlatStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.flatstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `DataGridViewButtonColumn` to `Flat` and set it's `Style.BackColor` to the color you want:

```
var C1 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn() { Name = "C1" };
C1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
C1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

**Change BackColor of a Single Cell**

If you want to set different colors for different cells, after setting `FlatStyle` of column or cell to `Flat`, it's enough to set `Style.BackColor` of different cells to different colors:

```
var cell = ((DataGridViewButtonCell)dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0]);
cell.FlatStyle =  FlatStyle.Flat;
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

If you want to change back color of a cell conditionally, you can do it in a `CellFormatting` event based on cell value.

**Note**

If you prefer standard look and feel of a `Button` instead of flat style, you can handle `CellPaint` event:

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
        return;
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) // Also you can check for specific row by e.RowIndex
    {
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All
            & ~( DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground));
        var r = e.CellBounds;
        r.Inflate(-4, -4);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, r);
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aghael, I only want to set colors for different cells in the column not the whole column

Comment: If you want to set different colors for different cells, after setting `FlatStyle` of `Column` to `Flat`, it's enough to set `Style.BackColor` of different cells to different colors.

Comment: Make sure to read the last code section, it enables you to use standard look and feel of a button instead of flat style. Also keep in mind, using `CellFormatting` event is much better than a for loop.