# Changing DataGridViewButton Color C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to figure out how to change the colour of my button but it seems to be overwritten by my code for alternating row colours, i cant figure out how to make it so i can have alternating row colours and have a red delete button.

Button Code:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn btnDelete = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        dgvCarsPurchased.Columns.Add(btnDelete);
        btnDelete.HeaderText = "Delete";
        btnDelete.Text = "Delete Record";
        btnDelete.Name = "btnDelete";
        btnDelete.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        btnDelete.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        btnDelete.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

        btnDelete.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
```

Alternating Row Colours

```
this.dgvCarsPurchased.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#3E606F");
        this.dgvCarsPurchased.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor =
            ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#91AA9D");
```

Comment: [Change color of Button in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40278638/3110834)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use the CellFormatting event:

```
private void dgvStatus_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != btnDelete.Index || e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    if (e.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#3E606F");        
    else
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#91AA9D");
}
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to change `DefaultCellStyle` to `CellTemplate`.

Example:

```
btnDelete.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
btnDelete.CellTemplate.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
btnDelete.CellTemplate.Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
```