# BackColor for DataGridView buttons is only affected to buttons after button only C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I wanted to set the `BackColor` of `DataGridViewButtonColumn` button so I wrote this piece of code,

```
public void searchData(string searchString)
        {
            string sQuery = "SELECT indexno,firstname,lastname,address,gender,dob,email,faculty,mobile FROM student WHERE CONCAT(`indexno`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `address`, `gender`, `dob`, `email`, `faculty`, `mobile`) LIKE '%" + searchString + "%'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sQuery, db.getConnection());
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            gridviewtable.DataSource = table;

            // --- edit n delete buttons ---
            DataGridViewButtonColumn editBtn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            DataGridViewButtonColumn delBtn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

            // -edit btn -
            editBtn.HeaderText = "Edit";
            editBtn.Name = "Edit";
            editBtn.Text = "Edit";
            editBtn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            editBtn.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
            editBtn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            editBtn.Width = 50;
            // - del btn-
            delBtn.HeaderText = "Delete";
            delBtn.Name = "Delete";
            delBtn.Text = "Delete";
            delBtn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            delBtn.Width = 50;

            gridviewtable.Columns.Add(editBtn);
            gridviewtable.Columns.Add(delBtn);

        }
```

It changes the button back color, but only affected to some buttons only(**button after a button**) as shown in the image.
[image] 
Hoping to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi @Avishka, do you want to change the Button's backcolor or the Row BackColor?

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina Button's backcolor, like shown in the image

Comment: It seems like it is `AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle` that take over here because every 2nd Row it is coming back to the default

Comment: Handle the [DataGridView.CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.8), check if the `e.ColumnIndex` is the `Edit` column, and set the `e.CellStyle.BackColor` if so. See the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to check for your `AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle` and set it as well:

```
gridviewtable.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
gridviewtable.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
```

But because we want to edit the Buttons' Backcolor, it's better and easier for you to configure a `Style` like this:

```
//Set the Background Color
Color bgColor = Color.Tomato;
Color frColor = Color.Black;

//Set the Button Style
DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle
{
    BackColor = bgColor,
    ForeColor = frColor
};

//I prefer to iterate over my Dgv
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvSheetList.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewButtonCell editBtn = (DataGridViewButtonCell)row.Cells[0].ButtonName;   //Cells[ColumnNumber]
    editBtn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;    //It's easier to override use Popup
    editBtn.Style = style;      //<--- You apply the Style here
}
```

> For further research about Datagridview buttons, you may go here as well [Change Color of Button in DataGridView Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586829/change-color-of-button-in-datagridview-cell)

Hope this will help you!

Blessings,

Comment: I really like the use of style! Thanks @Tsiriniaina. It inspires me of what I can do

Comment: @Tsiriniaina Rakotonirina, As you mentioned above, the problem is in `dataGridViewCellStyle2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Tomato;
            this.gridviewtable.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle2;` commenting out the code line fixed the issue. But is it okay to commenting out the style?